# Blank file when saving ggplot2 bar plot into pdf (windows 7)

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting and saving PDFs in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745675/plotting-and-saving-pdfs-in-a-loop)

Newbie's issues.
My tab separated input data looks like that:

```
x y
1 50
2 25
3 60
4 25
5 90
6 100
```

Here is my code file "code.R":

```
data <- read.table("input",header=T,sep="\t")
pdf("output.pdf")
ggplot (data,aes(x=x,y=y) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
dev.off()
```

I run the code with the command below and don't get any error message in return:

```
source("code.R")
```

The code generates the "output.pdf" file but it is blank (error when I want to open it).

When I enter manually in my R terminal the 1st then the 2nd line of the above code, the graph looks correct in the graphic device.

When I write the lines below in a file and run the file, nothing happen (no errors, no graphic device window)

```
data <- read.table("input",header=T,sep="\t")
ggplot (data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The line endings of both input and code files are in windows format.
I also tried `data <- as.data.frame(read.table(...))` but it changes nothing.
I really don't see what's wrong in my code...

Any advice and explanations would be great !
Thanks !

Comment: Duplicate. Read R-FAQ 7.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a close parentheses for your ggplot call.

This line:

```
ggplot (data,aes(x=x,y=y) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Should be:

```
ggplot (data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Or you can try ggsave() instead of pdf() dev.off() like this:

```
ggplot (data,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
ggsave("output.pdf")
```

Don't mix the two methods.

Comment: Doesn't explain why he gets a blank plot.

Comment: Typo sorry. The problem comes from something else as it works when I enter the code manually in R terminal to output the plot in the graphic device.

Comment: I tried it with the edit and it works.  Without the edit, I get the same behavior as lqdo2000 described.

Comment: Of course I set my working directory before read.table.     setwd("/Path/to/directory/data/is/in/")

Comment: @Nathan G: same, I'm in the right directory.

Comment: @DWin: maybe it is just a detail but I don't get a blank plot, I get a blank file without page (I cannot open the file).

Comment: @ldqdo2000 I edited my answer to include another method.  It's worth a shot if you can't get the other method to work.

Comment: @Nathan G: it works great with `ggsave`. Thanks a lot !